# Trying to reverse engineer serialized object

Tags: reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a 48 hex digit result from an undocumented API. I'm 99% sure it's a serialised version of an object created by the parameters I pass in.

So far I've gathered some data based on the parameters I pass in:

```
ID      Date        Integer1  Integer2  Result in hex (from Base64 Decode)
0471A   29 Nov 13       0       1       C91CFD6C27FBE7DEC5E8D1B6A4A8A2281656E439184A1F55
0471    29 Nov 13       0       1       9B8D85C7F72D12317E103D8C03A4E872AB09B51F84947775
0471    29 Nov 13       1       1       9B8D85C7F72D12317E103D8C03A4E8720005E3299E478F30
0471    29 Nov 13       1       2       9B8D85C7F72D12317E103D8C03A4E872C0FA99D1FAB9C7C3
0471A   30 Nov 13       0       1       B16D5AC863205E7C270C1CFFEBF05DFE287494D697A9EBE0
0471    30 Nov 13       0       1       BCCF1F4CC7E916D7A97FEFD79AF1A62D35D017565E18214C
0471    30 Nov 13       1       1       BCCF1F4CC7E916D7A97FEFD79AF1A62DAE5DD758EC44527B
0471A   1st Dec 13      0       1       DE792B7BC4DF1BBD3E601D11A96DF4CE658F1D19814FB6AE
0471    1st Dec 13      0       1       6183EE49649D328FC3AAE785ADB76458055B39FC27A201A9
0471    1st Dec 13      1       1       6183EE49649D328FC3AAE785ADB76458860BA31BFD48B872
0471    1st Dec 13      0       2       6183EE49649D328FC3AAE785ADB764585DC848A2ED78B57A
0471    2nd Dec 13      0       1       16CA69D44EC179AFA8E8DBF4B260DBA724F0BED94EFFD359
```

I've noticed that if the ID and Date are the same, then the first half of the bytes of the result are also the same. What should be my next step to decode this data?

Comment: How much weeks or months of work are you willing to spend? Are you sure it is worthwhile? Can't you use some other API (or some free software whose source code you could study)?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a one way hash of some sort?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was willing to spend a couple of days on it, however I'm now less certain it's an object and might instead be a hash that is used to lookup the object in question from an internal database. Will put this project on hold for the time being.